# How to debug a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to debug a jquery plugin? When I open the plugin in visual studio it is shown as a single line in the editor. Also, when debugging with firebug, the plugin code is shown as a series of lines with no indentation which makes it hard to follow.

JD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the debug (non-minified) version of the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You can try unminifying with a tool like this one http://jsbeautifier.org/ if you don't have access to the unminified file.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug is very helpful as well. But, like SLaks said, unless you have the non-compressed, debug (also called dev) version, line numbers of problems will most likely be useless.